# Some image files are deleted during output/moving with batch file

Tags: batch, script, imagemagick

I've been having an issue for a while now with various versions of a batch file script I have been using to assist with listing items on my WordPress/woocommerce page. The script seems to occasionally delete between 0 and 2 images indiscriminately.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "targetDirectory=C:\Path\to\target\folder"
set "outputDirectory=C:\Path\to\output\folder"

pushd "%targetDirectory%"

for %%F in (*.*) do (
    set "outputFile=!outputDirectory!\%%~nF.webp"
    magick "%%F" "!outputFile!"
)

echo Files in %targetDirectory% have been converted to WebP format and stored in %outputDirectory%.

popd

echo Deleting original files...
del /Q "%targetDirectory%\*.*"

echo Original files in %targetDirectory% have been deleted.

timeout /nobreak /t 3 >nul
endlocal
```

The script is just supposed to convert the images in one folder to webp files and move them to the output folder.

I used ChatGPT to generate the script because I know very little about coding, but the code looks rather simple/short and I can't see why random images would sometimes be deleted.

It doesn't seem to discriminate between different original file types either when I checked the missing output files.

Answer (score 0):

The script is deleting all the input files, regardless of whether or not magick was successful; there's no error checking. I'm guessing that's why some files are not getting converted and just being deleted.

Viewing the script's output might confirm, if magick gives any feedback about errors, I'm not sure.

---

FYI, here's a link to another question about adding error checking to a windows batch file (similar to bash in some ways, I wonder which came first):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164049/batch-files-error-handling

---

Just for fun, I tried seeing what a bash version of a script could look like... Run `magick` on files from indir, changing the filename by dropping everything after the last period and adding "webp", and then erasing successful files or moving failed files to faildir:

```
#!/bin/bash
indir="/path/to/input dir"
outdir="/path/to/output dir"
faildir="/path/to/fail dir"

for i in "$indir"/* ; do
magick "$i" "$outdir/$(basename "${i%.*}.webp")" && {
    echo success, removing $i; rm -v "$i"; } || {
    echo "fail on $i, moving to $faildir"; mv "$i" -t "$faildir"; } 
done
```

A batch file version *could* be similar, it appears to use the same `&&` and `||` success/fail operators, possibly replacing the curly brackets with regular round brackets?

Comment: Looks like I've got some learning to do. I tried to recreate the issue but all the image files are going through after a few tries. I might need to get chatgpt to add that error level code tomorrow.

Comment: I'd recommend to jump-start with either Python or any other similar scripting language instead: The syntax is far more readable, and therefore much easier to understand, modify and fault find. You may still (need to) use `magick` for the actual conversion, unless you can find e.g. a Python native replacement.

Comment: That's a nice thing about tools like chatgpt, just say "convert this script to python" or bash, or even rust/C/etc and you're nearly done

Comment: @MonkeyNoodles It is hard to know for sure how it's failing without seeing all the output (which could be VERY long depending on magick's verboseness and number of files) but hopefully this answered the why it's failing. I'd probably only delete a file immediately after a successful magick conversion ( with the `&&` operator), instead of flagging a failed file and then doing something with it, but maybe the chatbot doesn't mind the extra work ;-) If the answer was helpful, please do remember to upvote/mark as correct (checkmark)

Comment: @MonkeyNoodles “I might need to get chatgpt to add that error level code tomorrow.” No. At this point, debug on your own. It should be a simple fix. But do not trust a large language model to fix what it already created as broken.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Going to use all the assistance to help with figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

> *The script seems to occasionally delete between 0 and 2 images indiscriminately.*
>
> Change the way you do it, converting all and deleting the source does not operate in result control per execution/file.
>
> But convert your files, then check each source file has its version    converted to `SameFileName.WebP`, if you have, delete the file otherwise, report the error on screen without deleting the file originating from the error.

---

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_targetDirectory=C:\Path\to\target\folder"
set "_outputDirectory=C:\Path\to\output\folder"

pushd "%_targetDirectory%" && (
     for %%F in (*.*) do magick "%%~F" "!outputDirectory!\%%~nF.webp"
    ) || exit /b 1

echo/Files in %_targetDirectory% have been converted 
echo/to WebP format and stored in %_outputDirectory%.

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%F in (`
     dir /a:-d /b *.* ^| findstr /veic:.webp
   `) do if exist "!_outputDirectory!\%%~nF.webp" (
         del /Q "%_targetDirectory%\%%~nxF"
        )else echo/ERROR: "!outputDirectory!\%%~nF.webp"

popd & timeout /nobreak /t 3 >nul & endlocal
```

---

1. Convert your files into your current `for` loop.
2. Use a second `for` loop to list and filter the files again.
3. Add an `if` to filter the output of the second loop and check the existence of the new file.
4. Whether it exists or not, take the action of deleting it or not for the relevant case.

---

- An alternative to **[WebP.exe/LibWebP-1.3.2](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/precompiled?hl=en)** users handling potential conversion success/error...

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_targetDir=C:\Path\To\Folder-Input"
set "_outputDir=C:\Path\To\Folder-Output"

set "_OutDir=%_outputDir:\=" & set "_OutDir=%"
set "_cWebP=C:\Program Files\LibWebP\bin\cwebp.exe"

cd /d "%_targetDir%" && =;( for %%F in =;(*.*);= do =;(
     2>&1 "%_cWebP%" -q 100 "%%~F" -o "!_outputDir!\%%~nF.webp" | findstr.exe /bei "ERROR.*.png'"
    );= || echo/.\"%%~nF.webp" ==^> zOk^^!! );= || exit /b 001

echo/Files in %_targetDir% have been converted to WebP format and stored in "..\!_OutDir!".

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%F in =;(` dir /a:-d /b *.* ^| findstr.exe /veic:.webp
   `);= do if exist "!_outputDir!\%%~nF.webp" =;( del /q /f "%_targetDir%\%%~nxF"
        );= else echo/ERROR File: "!_outputDir!\%%~nxF"

timeout.exe /nobreak /t 05 >nul & explorer.exe "!_targetDir!" & endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I will try the scripts and do more error finding. The deleted images still looks random to me. Doesn't look like a file type or naming convention being the issue..